# Calling C function from Swift shows different results in CLion than in Xcode

Tags: ios, c, swift, pointers

I am trying to call a C function from Swift , but I do not know exactly how to define variables to pass parameters. This is the function declaration:

```
/* Function Declarations */
extern void compute_feature_set(const double input[11025],
                                double M_data[], int M_size[2],
                                double D_data[], int D_size[2],
                                double DD_data[],
                                int DD_size[2],
                                double VT[10], double *mp,
                                double r_42[42], double *fM);
```

The data is an array of floats. So I tried ​​:

```
    let s = data.compactMap{ Double($0)}
    
    var mSize = Array<Int32>(repeating:Int32(0.0), count:2)
    var dSize = Array<Int32>(repeating:Int32(0.0), count:2)
    var dD_Size = Array<Int32>(repeating:Int32(0.0), count:2)
    
    var mData =  Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:48)
    var dData =  Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:48)
    var dD_Data =  Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:48)
    
    var vt =  Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:10)
    var mp =  Double(0.0)
    var r  = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:42)
    var fM = Double(0)

    compute_feature_set(s, &cout, &mSize, &vx, &dSize, &dD_Data, &dD_Size, &vcta, &mp, &r, &fM)
```

When I run the code in Clion with the following function it works fine and the output matches the expected values:

```
static void main_compute_feature_set(void)
{
    static double dv[11025];
    double DD_data[48];
    double D_data[48];
    double M_data[48];
    double r_42[42];
    double VT[10];
    double fM;
    double mp;
    int DD_size[2];
    int D_size[2];
    int M_size[2];
    /* Initialize function 'compute_feature_set' input arguments. */
    /* Initialize function input argument 'input'. */
    /* Call the entry-point 'compute_feature_set'. */
    argInit_11025x1_real_T(dv);
    compute_feature_set(dv, M_data, M_size, D_data, D_size,
                      DD_data, Dd_size, VT,
                      &mp, r_42, &fM);
}
```

However, when I run my implementation in Swift, I get very different results.

Comment: Looks like the only input param to the C function is the first one, so it looks like there are some conversion problems on the side of the Swift code. What's `data`? What kind of values are you transforming from? Does the C function expect exactly 11025 elements? If yes, does the `compactMap` call generate this amount of doubles?

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing pointers of the Arrays, rather than the Arrays directly.

[Using Imported C Functions in Swift | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift)

> ### Call Functions with Pointer Parameters
>
> Whenever possible, Swift avoids giving you direct access to pointers. When importing C function parameters, however, Swift maps pointer parameters to standard library pointer types.
> The following tables use Type as a placeholder type name to indicate syntax for the mappings.
>
> For return types, variables, and arguments, the following mappings apply:
>
> | C Syntax | Swift Syntax |
> | --- | --- |
> | `const Type *` | `UnsafePointer<Type>` |
> | `Type *` | `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` |

`double[]` is pretty much equivalent to `double *` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem with your code is passing data to your function. You use `compactMap` to make an `Array` of `Double` and then pass the pointer of this array. But `Array` and `Double` are `struct` in Swift so you pass the pointer of struct with structs instead of array of `double` values.

To convert your data to array of bytes you should use `withUnsafeBytes` e.g.:

Swift:

```swift
let data = Data([0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd])
data.withUnsafeBytes {
    passData($0)
}
```

C/ObjC:

```
void passData(const double input[11025]) {
    NSLog(@"%x", input[0]); // Prints: ddccbbaa
}
```